# Hazelcast throws java.io.NotSerializableException for Predicate based supplier for Aggregate

Tags: java, client, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Below is the code for my attempt to run aggregates on hazelcast using Hazelcast Client. The first aggregate works out just fine, but the 2nd one throws an java.io.NotSerializableException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment

My code:

```
public class AggregateExperiment {
    public void runTest(){
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
        clientConfig.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<String, Integer> map = client.getMap("customers");
        Supplier<String, Integer, Integer> supplier = Supplier.all();
// Choose the average aggregation
        Aggregation<String, Integer, Integer> aggregation = Aggregations.integerAvg();
        int average  =  map.aggregate(supplier, aggregation);
        System.out.println("Average of inputs = "+average);

        supplier = Supplier.fromKeyPredicate(new MyKeyPredicate());
// Choose the sum aggregation
        aggregation = Aggregations.integerSum();
        average  =  map.aggregate(supplier, aggregation );
        System.out.println("Average of inputs = "+average);

    }

    public class MyKeyPredicate implements KeyPredicate<String> {
        public boolean evaluate(String key) {
            return Integer.parseInt(key) % 4 == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error messages :

```
Average of inputs = 1
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:988)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:960)
    at co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment.runTest(AggregateExperiment.java:31)
    at co.near.hazelcast.MainExperiment.main(MainExperiment.java:131)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:188)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.access$000(ClientInvocationFuture.java:41)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$1.run(ClientInvocationFuture.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:380)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:307)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.KeyPredicateSupplier.writeData(KeyPredicateSupplier.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:140)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:39)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.SupplierConsumingMapper.writeData(SupplierConsumingMapper.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:140)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:39)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.client.ClientMapReduceRequest.writeData(ClientMapReduceRequest.java:204)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.client.ClientMapReduceRequest.write(ClientMapReduceRequest.java:173)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.client.ClientRequest.writePortable(ClientRequest.java:86)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.writeInternal(PortableSerializer.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.write(PortableSerializer.java:53)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.write(PortableSerializer.java:29)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport.send(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:104)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnRandomTarget(ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invokeOnSelection(ClientInvocation.java:163)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapReduceProxy$ClientJob.invoke(ClientMapReduceProxy.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.AbstractJob.submit(AbstractJob.java:119)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.AbstractJob$ReducingSubmittableJobImpl.submit(AbstractJob.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:985)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:960)
    at co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment.runTest(AggregateExperiment.java:31)
    at co.near.hazelcast.MainExperiment.main(MainExperiment.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:175)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:223)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.KeyPredicateSupplier.writeData(KeyPredicateSupplier.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:140)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:39)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.SupplierConsumingMapper.writeData(SupplierConsumingMapper.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:140)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:39)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:305)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:315)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.client.ClientMapReduceRequest.writeData(ClientMapReduceRequest.java:204)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.client.ClientMapReduceRequest.write(ClientMapReduceRequest.java:173)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.client.ClientRequest.writePortable(ClientRequest.java:86)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.writeInternal(PortableSerializer.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.write(PortableSerializer.java:53)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.PortableSerializer.write(PortableSerializer.java:29)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:37)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:227)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceSupport.send(ClientInvocationServiceSupport.java:104)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnRandomTarget(ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invokeOnSelection(ClientInvocation.java:163)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapReduceProxy$ClientJob.invoke(ClientMapReduceProxy.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.AbstractJob.submit(AbstractJob.java:119)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.AbstractJob$ReducingSubmittableJobImpl.submit(AbstractJob.java:348)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:985)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.aggregate(ClientMapProxy.java:960)
    at co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment.runTest(AggregateExperiment.java:31)
    at co.near.hazelcast.MainExperiment.main(MainExperiment.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast as of now does not support distributed classloading which would be needed for the code above to work properly.

An issue is github is already opened for the same https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7394

For now, those who really want to use Hazelcast in this manner can explore https://github.com/serkan-ozal/hermgen as well

Answer (score 2):

Instances of the inner class `MyKeyPredicate` contain an implicit reference to parent `AggregateExperiment` instance. This makes `MyKeyPredicate` not serializable. You should make `MyKeyPredicate` static:

```
public static class MyKeyPredicate implements KeyPredicate<String> {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I made the class static, but now it throws the following error  
-----  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.near.hazelcast.AggregateExperiment$MyKeyPredicate

Comment: I can only guess that your classes (such as MyKeyPredicate) should be in the classpath of all nodes in the hazelcast cluster.

Comment: If I am running in a HazelcastClient, how do I get it done ?

Comment: You need to include the jar containing the predicate to the set of jars being used on the server. Hazelcast doesn't support distributed classloading.